# How long does it take to stain cells?

Tags: staining, fluorescent-microscopy

I'm never going to run these type of experiments but I do need to have a good idea of their timescale. After I fix my cells, if I stained my cells with histology stains like DAPI, Fluorescein, and various labeled antibodies, how long do I have to wait before I can examine my cells with microscopy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For fluorescence immunocytochemistry, there are 3 main incubations that determine duration of the procedure. Generally it takes 2 days to stain your cells before you can visualize them. Once cells or tissue are fixed onto glass, you first incubate with a primary antibody to directly target a specific antigen(s), usually overnight. After primary labelling, a secondary antibody is applied to target the primary antibody, which usually takes a few hours. These secondary antibodies come conjugated to some fluorescent dye (Cy5, TRITC, FITC, AlexaFluors, etc). A nuclear counterstain is really quick, only 5 minutes. After all the labelling and nuclear stain, you can mount the coverslip with mounting media and once it cures you can visualize them.

Abcam has one of many quick [reference guides](http://www.abcam.com/index.html?pageconfig=resource&rid=11459).

Comment: The temperature plays an important role, too: incubating at 4°C or at RT makes a big difference.

Comment: Certainly. I also left out blocking which is arguably most critical to the process, but on the time scale of the whole procedure, is relatively quick (30-60 minutes). @bobthejoe was simply asking for an idea of total time.

Comment: And another factor is what you are staining: times are shorter for cells in culture compared to tissue slices (i.e.: ICC vs IHC), as the antibody will need time to deeply penetrate in the tissue.